# The command npm audit-level is not working when trying to change level to high

Tags: node.js, npm, audit, npm-audit

I have a front-end app with NodeJS and I am trying to make the npm audit break only on high or critical vulnerabilities, so I tried to change the audit-level as specified in the documentation, but it would still return the low vulnerabilities as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42AE8.png)

```
npm set audit-level high
npm config set audit-level high
npm audit
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

My npm version is 6.14.5
My NodeJS version is 10.17.0

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, I asked the same question myself so I thought I'd answer to help the next person.

Based on the [discussion here](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1471), the `--audit-level` parameter dictates if the npm audit fails (exits with `1`) or not (exits with `0`). That means, if you specify `--audit-level=critical`, it will exit with `1` if there is a critical vulnerability, else it will exist with `0`. It does not however control/filter the report/output, which I find annoying.

As a work-around, I do this to only output/report the levels I'm concerned with. It is not very elegant but it helps me, if the list of vulnerabilities is so long:

```
npm audit --parseable | grep high
```

Comment: Good note on the purpose of `--audit-level` parameter, but `--parseable` does not have any effect on the output of the audit in NPM version `9.6.7`. There is a `--json` flag that I'm currently playing with on Pomodoro breaks, to see if I can coax it into providing useable, filtered output...

Answer (score 1):

As Frank already mentioned `--audit-level` only effects to exit code returned by `npm audit`. If you're looking to simplify the text output, you'll have to parse it yourself. Here's one solution I souped up using `npm` version `9.6.7`'s `--json` flag in conjunction with [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/):

```
npm audit --json | jq '.vulnerabilities[] | select(.severity == "high") | .name'
```

This just outputs the names of the packages with a `"high"` vulnerability, but you could play with this however you like to get output that is more useful to you. Remove the  `| .name` from the end of the `jq` query to see, for example, the entire object that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you have to run:

```
npm audit --json | jq '.vulnerabilities[] | select (.severity == \"critical\")'
```

On Linux, as J.M Janson told, you can do:

```
npm audit --json | jq '.vulnerabilities[] | select(.severity == "high") | .name'
```